# How to aggregate Weather Data from county to state level?

Tags: predictive-modeling, data, data-analysis

I am doing a prediction of forest fire risk using the weather data and the fire incident data. I have data related to different county and the weather data on the day of the incident. As the incident data shows all incident occurred, I am generating negative data of fire event not occuring in the days when the incident is not reported.

My question is that on what basis should I give the weather data for the negative data points. Because they don't belong to any county(I have data of all the counties from california)

Other question is how to predict a fire event for the entire state if I have county data. Can I predict that a fire incident may occur in the state. Please suggest how to aggregate data and approach this problem.